# Como gerenciar um git para dois domínios?

Tags: git, github, versionamento

Eu tenho um site no qual estou trabalhando, onde estamos começando agora instalar controle de versão e estamos com dificuldade em testar o site antes de enviá-lo para produção.

Temos os seguinte domínios:

```
dominioprincipal.com.br
dev.dominioprincipal.com.br
```

Há a possibilidade de criar algum branch de desenvolvimento no dev.dominioprincipal.com.br e permanecer o dominioprincipal.com.br no master?

OUTRA OPÇÃO:
sabemos que nossa hospedagem é gerenciada pelo cpanel, onde deve-se criar um .cpanel.yml para mover de uma pasta previamente criada para repositorios git para a pasta do dominio principal. Porém, este arquivo deve ser versionado, e isso gera retrabalho. Alguma recomendação?

ATUALIZAÇÃO

[image: Estrutura de páginas]

Atualmente trabalhamos com esta estrutura, onde fazemos o commit para as pastas dentro de repositório, onde cada um deve ter seu .cpanel.yml para redirecionar para o public_html respectivo, porém, como o .cpanel.yml deve ser versionado para que funcione (até onde sabemos atualmente) sempre que fazemos uma novo "envio" para um site diferente, ele sobrescreve este arquivo (que é basicamente o nosso principal problema)

Comment: 1 - Sim, há. Eu tenho 2 e vou fazendo push para dev e só quando está pronto faço o push de tudo para a master. 2 - Mudem isso para a amazon que depois podem fazer deploy diretamente para o dev e para o de produção. 2 servidores básicos, 1 para cada. ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Poderia me dar mais informações sobre como você faz este processo? Pois me parece que é exatamente o que preciso!

Comment: Não seria o caso de adicionar um `remote`? Daí você fazer o push dos branches só no seu respectivo repositório...

Comment: Você pode utilizar os triggers pós-push para iniciar o processo de build de cada uma das *versões*. Por exemplo, toda vez que faz o push na branch de dev você libera o build no dev e o mesmo com prod. GitHub permite você configurar webhooks que fazem esse serviço. Vale também estudar serviços de CI, como Jenkins

Comment: @FelipeAvelar adicionei informações que podem esclarecer um pouco mais, ajudou?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss  adicionei informações que podem esclarecer um pouco mais, ajudou?

Comment: Se o problema for sobrescrever um arquivo que não deveria ser sobrescrito, o que precisa ser feito é remover o arquivo do versionamento, com git rm e depois adicionar no .gitignore...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar a questão não é remover o arquivo, a questão é: posso de alguma forma visualizar o que está sendo desenvolvido sem exibir ao usuário final? Este arquivo está nos dando problema... exemplo: branch master e branch dev, posso apenas eu visualizar o dev? Inclusive, mil desculpas por não saber explicar exatamente minha dúvida... kkkkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de o Git ser usado como o meio principal de publicação, ele não é a única ferramenta a ser utilizada e nesse caso você deve fazer uso de uma ferramenta de pipeline, que irá ajudar em um processo de compilação (no seu caso parece ser páginas estáticas, sim), trocar variáveis de ambiente, etc...

Algumas ferramentas que pode te ajudar, disponíveis na nuvem e free ou inicialmente free:

- [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions)
- [Azure Pipelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/pipelines/)
- [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/login)
- [Buddy](https://buddy.works/)

Inicialmente pode parece que você está adicionando complexidade ao desenvolvimento, mas ter um pipeline automatizado irá te trazer benefícios, por exemplo, não deixar váriáveis de ambiente em código; segurança, por exemplo, fazer separação do ambiente de dev e produção, e a promoção segura através de promoção.

Comment: Não era exatamente este o meu problema, porém ao pesquisar e conhecer as tecnologias mencionadas eu consegui resolver meu problema... Agradeço de coração meu amigo!